# Are rings $\mathbb {R}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ and $\mathbb {R}[X]/(X^2 − 1)$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

So my proof is $\mathbb {R}[x]$ is a PID so it is an integral domain

$(x^2 + 1)$ is irreducible as it has no roots and is of degree 2

since $\mathbb {R}[x]$ is an integral domain $(x^2 + 1)$ is prime

so $\mathbb {R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field

$(x^2-1)$ is reducible $(x-1)(x+1)$

so $\mathbb {R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is not a field so it can not be isomorphic

Another way:

Assume ∃ a isomorphism Φ such that $ Φ:\mathbb {R}[x]/(x^2-1) → \mathbb {R}[x]/(x^2+1) $

since $(x^2-1)$ is reducible $ ∃ t ∈ \mathbb {R}[x]/(x^2-1),∃ y ∈ \mathbb {R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ such that $ty=0$ where $t≠0,y≠0$

$ Φ(ty) = Φ(0) = 0$

$Φ(ty) = Φ(t)Φ(y) ≠ 0$ since $(x^2+1)$ is not reducible

$Φ(t) ≠ 0,Φ(y) ≠ 0$ since we assume $Φ$ is an isomorphism only the $0$ element can map to the $0$ element

so $Φ(ty) ≠ Φ(t)Φ(y)$ there is a contradiction $Φ$ cannot be an isomorphism

Comment: The first method is correct.  The second method is not correct, as you assume that $\Phi(x)=x$ and there might be some other isomorphism you're not considering.  You should really use $x$ on the LHS and $y$ on the RHS to emphasize that these two variables are not connected.

Comment: I edited the answer is it correct now?

Comment: it looks good, but the notation is not, $x\in\Phi:\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ has no sense. On the other hand, to make the solution more explicit intead of taking some arbitrary $x$ and $y$ such that $xy=0$ you can give an explicit $x$ and an explicit $y$. Another isue is that you are naming $x$ as the variable of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ and as an arbitrary element of the ring. Try to correct these things, it should be easy.

Comment: i did have an explicit x which I have now labeled t and y but the commenter above had said that the isomorphism may not map like that so I should generalize it look at the edits for the original one

Comment: @BingBong It does look good now.  Note that it's similar to the first proof; what you have shown is that an integral domain cannot be isomorphic to a non-integral domain.  Since $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is an integral domain and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ isn't, the result follows.